# Where does contract’s call failure behavior is definied in the yellow paper?

Tags: evm, yellow-paper, failed-transaction, stack

If a contract’s call succeeds then `0x1` is pushed on the stack and `0x0` otherwise.
Where is this behavior defined in the yellow paper ?

Also, are there cases were sending ether isn’t reverted in recipient but `0x0` or nothing is pushed on the stack ?

Comment: For the second question - yes, if you use `address.send` instead of `address.transfer` (fail silently).

Comment: @goodvibration : I’m not talking about solidity but the evm itself. Also I’m talking about not reverted in the child instead of not reverted in the caller.

Comment: then please show your code in order to clarify your question / thoughts / design / intentions.

Comment: @goodvibration it’s about the yellow paper/design. There’s no code.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that a 0x0 is pushed to the stack on a failed call and 0x1 for a successful call is specified under the description of CALL on page 35 of the [yellowpaper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf).

To answer your second question, no, there are no cases where CALL pushes 0x0 to the stack without the transfer of ETH being reverted.

Small note: If you are thinking of a way to get ETH into a contract that doesn't want ETH in it, there are still two ways to force it there. You can either mine a block with said address as the recipient of the block reward, or you can SELFDESTRUCT a contract with said address specified as the recipient of ETH.

Comment: I’m thinking about way to return failure to a caller which uses `if( !recipient.call.value(value)() ) money[msg.sender] += value;` in solidity while still keeping the Ethers in `recipient`. If nothing is pushed on the stack then the last value which is `0x0` is used in place which means it works too.

Comment: If there's a failure, then the ether will never remain in `recipient`. If you absolutely need it to, then you could create a contract that calls `selfDestruct(recipient)`, send the eth to it, and have it do the self destruct.

Comment: I’m thinking about an other way to return the code of a failure without actually having a failure. `selfDestruct(recipient)` is about returning the code of success without keeping the money while I want to keep the money without returning the code of success.

Comment: If you control the calling and receiving address, then you can just have the receiving contract have a function like `transferEth` that never fails, but returns a boolean saying whether it succeeded or failed. If you don't control the receiving address, then there's nothing you can really do. If you control the receiver but not the caller, then the caller will have to call this specific function instead of just transferring to the fallback function.

Comment: The point if I found a contract which does `if( !recipient.call.value(value)() ) money[msg.sender] += value;` at [line 2098](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa52e014b3f5cc48287c2d483a3e026c32cc76e6d#code) instead of reverting so if there’s a way for `if( !recipient.call.value(value)() ) ` to be true even without a revert, then there’s a possibility for an attacker to steal funds.

Comment: There is no way for `recipient.call.value(value)()` to be false while not reverting the transfer of `value` as well. It does, however, look like an opportunity for reentrancy. It's a large contract though and I don't have the availability to analyse if they're safe against it.

Comment: There’s no possible reentrancy since the balanceof msd.sender is substracted before the call (hence the fact that’s it recredited on failure). Everything is in the function: how (outside the function) there’s could be exists code which would makes `playerWithdrawPendingTransactions()` vulnerable to reentrancy?